# Apache Http Components - How to timeout CONNECT request to a proxy?

Tags: proxy, apache-httpcomponents

**Timeout Without Using Proxy**

I start netcat in my local as follows, which basically listens to connections on port 9090:

```
netcat -l -p 9090
```

And using [Apache HttpComponents](https://hc.apache.org/), I create a connection to it with a timeout of 4 seconds..

```
RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
        .setSocketTimeout(4000)
        .setConnectTimeout(4000)
        .setConnectionRequestTimeout(4000)
        .build();

HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://127.0.0.1:9090");
httpget.setConfig(requestConfig);

try (CloseableHttpResponse response = HttpClients.createDefault().execute(httpget)) {}
```

In terminal (where I have `netcat` running) I see:

```
??]?D???;#???9?Mۡ?NR?w?{)?V?$?(=?&?*kj?
?5??98?#?'<?%?)g@?  ?/??32?,?+?0??.?2???/??-?1???D

<!-- 4 seconds later -->
read(net): Connection reset by peer
```

In client side what I see is:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: 
Connect to 127.0.0.1:9090 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Read timed out
```

This is all expected.

**Timeout Using Proxy**

I change the client code slightly and configure a proxy, following the docs [here](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html#d5e485).

```
RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
         .setSocketTimeout(4000)
         .setConnectTimeout(4000)
         .setConnectionRequestTimeout(4000)
         .build();

HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("127.0.0.1", 9090);
DefaultProxyRoutePlanner routePlanner = new DefaultProxyRoutePlanner(proxy);
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
        .setRoutePlanner(routePlanner)
        .build();

HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("https://127.0.0.1:9090");
httpget.setConfig(requestConfig);

try (CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget)) {}
```

And again start netcat, and this time on serverside

```
CONNECT 127.0.0.1:9090 HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:9090
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.4.1 (Java/1.8.0_212)
```

But timeout is not working for `CONNECT`. I just wait forever..

How can I configure the `httpclient` to timeout for 4 seconds just like in the first case I described?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RequestConfig` only take effect once a connection to the target via the specific route has been fully established . They do not apply to the SSL handshake or any CONNECT requests that take place prior to the main message exchange.

Configure socket timeout at the `ConnectionManager` level to ensure connection level operations time out after a certain period of inactivity.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility:

```java
// This part is the same..
httpget.setConfig(requestConfig);

ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
Callable<CloseableHttpResponse> callable = () -> {
    try (CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget)) {
        return response;
    }
};

Future<CloseableHttpResponse> future = executorService.submit(callable);
try {
    future.get(4, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
} catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException | TimeoutException e) {
    httpget.abort();
    executorService.shutdownNow();
}
```

But I am open to other suggestions..